# Play video based on orientation

Tags: android, video

im new one for android. im developing one application that
application getting videos from sd card and display thumbnail view.
after user click any one video it will be play its working fine to me.
but if that video file is taken from landscape means it will be play
landscape, or that video file taken from portrait means it will play
portrait view.so i search this long time but i could not find
anything. so any one knows any idea share with me.

Comment: did u able to succeed to get the orientation of video?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use different layout files for different orientations, place in /layout and /layout-land.

Comment: ya im getting what u will saying that is fine. how can i find which video uri is landscape or portrait

Comment: If you want to play specific video depending on orientation, check this snippet.

Comment: thanks for ur response. but i dont need to get screen orientation what im exactly need how to find that video was taken from landscape mode or Portia mode.